# Extracting href from a class within other div/id classes with jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

Hello I am trying to extract the first href from within the "title" class from the following source (the source is only part of the whole page however I am using the entire page):

```html
div id="atfResults" class="list results ">
<div id="result_0" class="result firstRow product" name="0006754023">
    <div id="srNum_0" class="number">1.</div>
        <div class="image">
        <a href="http://www.amazon.co.uk/Essential-Modern-Classics-J-Tolkien/dp/0006754023/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1316504574&amp;sr=8-1">
        <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31ZcWU6HN4L._AA115_.jpg" class="productImage" alt="Product Details">
</a>
</div>
<div class="data">
    <div class="title">
<a class="title titleHover" href="http://www.amazon.co.uk/Essential-Modern-Classics-J-Tolkien/dp/0006754023/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1316504574&amp;sr=8-1">Essential Modern Classics - The Hobbit</a>
        <span class="ptBrand">by J. R. R. Tolkien</span>
 <span class="bindingAndRelease">(<span class="binding">Paperback</span> -&nbsp;2 Apr 2009)</span>
        </div>
```

I have tried several variations of both the select function and also getElementByClass but all have given me a "null" value such as:

```
Document firstSearchPage = Jsoup.connect(fullST).get();
Element link = firstSearchPage.select("div.title").first();
```

If someone could help me with a solution to this problem and recommend some areas of reading so I can avoid this problem in future it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS selector `div.title`, returns a `<div class="title">`, not a link as you seem to think. If you want an `<a class="title">` then you should use the `a.title` selector.

```
Element link = document.select("a.title").first();
String href = link.absUrl("href");
// ...
```

Or if an `<a class="title">` can appear elsewhere in the document outside a `<div class="title">` before that point, then you need the following more specific selector:

```
Element link = document.select("div.title a.title").first();
String href = link.absUrl("href");
// ...
```

This will return the first `<a class="title">` which is a child of `<div class="title">`.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I still have the following problem however: Elements link = document.select("div.title a.title").first(); will not compile as it requires "Element". When i change this using either of your examples i get NullPointerException on the line: String href = link.absUrl("href");

Comment: The first was just a typo (perhaps caused by a habit), I fixed it in my answer. The second indicates that there's just no such element in the document.

Comment: I am not sure why i cannot find the required elements in the extracted code. Many of the main heading in the pages code that i try to extract return null when the headings appear in the inspect element window of my browser. Is it possible that i need to add more to the document.select for example (div.main div.searchtemplate div.etc) until i reach the part i need?

Comment: Perhaps it's populated by JavaScript? Jsoup doesn't execute JS code. Do rightclick and *View Source* in browser to see what Jsoup would retrieve (not *Inspect Element*! it intercepts on current HTML DOM tree not on retrieved source). Do `System.out.println(document.html())` to see whatever Jsoup retrieved.

Comment: thankyou so much for your help. i have it extracting the <div id="result_0"> which contains the information i need however the href i need is <div class="image> which is within the result_0 id. I have tried select("#result_0 div.image").first(); but this still returns null?