# JSoup - how to grab a href (url/link) immediately preceding a <span class = *>?

Tags: java, css-selectors, html-parsing, jsoup

Given the following :

```
<li class="med grey mkp2">
    <a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B004N627KS/ref=sr_1_1_olp?ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1357396214&amp;sr=8-1&amp;keywords=097855073358&amp;condition=new"><span class="price bld">$28.15</span> new <span class="grey">(14 offers)</span></a> </li>
```

I need to grab the href, which sounds simple, right? However the only way I can find the correct list item to grab from is to get the `<span class="price bld">`, so the href I need preceeds it. It's similar to [Extracting href from a class within other div/id classes with jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481930/extracting-href-from-a-class-within-other-div-id-classes-with-jsoup), but in reverse.

There can be many list items with the css class "med grey mkp2", but I only need content from the ones with the noted span with class="price bld".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Yeah - uh...I tried to show the real url, but I guess the SO masters don't want to get slapped by Amazon!. It should still demonstrate my dilemma...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only select the target element (the `<a>`), not the child element (the `<span>`), otherwise it would only return `<span>` elements. In this particular case, you can use the `:has()` selector to check if the target element has the desired child element.

```
Elements elements = document.select("a:has(.price.bld)");
```

#### See also:

- [Jsoup selector cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

  > `:has(seletor)`: find elements that contain elements matching the selector; e.g. `div:has(p)`

Comment: hat's off to you. You saw past my question and found the root cause - and solved my problem. Of course I had to extract the href attribute also, but If I couldn't figure that out myself, i wouldn't have deserved your help. Thanks for your time!

Comment: `for (Element element : elements) String href = element.attr("href");`